# Operator<< can't output in the same line when object changed

Tags: c++

Test code:

```
    Date mydate{31,12,1976};
    cout <<mydate.set(1,1,1978)<< mydate << "\n";
    cout <<mydate;
```

output:

```
1-1-1978 31-12-1976

1-1-1978
```

opeator<< declaration for my class:

```
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  Date date);
```

operator<< definition for my class:

```
    std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os,  Date date)
    {
        return os << date.m_month_day <<" "<< date.m_month <<" "<< date.y_year<<" ";
    }
```

I am using extractor operator function for my class. But i can't output in the same line when object changed. As you can see. What should i do?

Comment: Please make a [mre]. In particular, the definition of `Date::set`. Also, before c++17, the order of evaluation of arguments to `cout` is unspecified.

Comment: I don't see anything strange? Two values are printed on one line, then an explicit newline, then a new value? What did you expect to get?

Answer (score 4):

You are making the assumption that in

```
cout << A << B;
```

that `A` must be evaluated before `B`. That is not true.

Of course the value of `A` must be output before the value of `B`, but that could happen even though `B` is evaluated before `A`. That is clearly what is happening in your case.

The simplest answer would be to upgrade to C++17. In C++17 the rules were changed so that (using the example above) `A` must be evaluated before `B`. If you're not able to upgrade to C++17 there's nothing you can do except change your code.